# How do I modify DataExplorer::create_report function to create a plot bar with percentage?

Tags: r, customization, percentage

I have this data set (it's an example). With my real data set, I have 100 categorical variables:

```
library(DataExplorer)

df <- data.frame(Sex = c("Male","Female","Male","Female","Male"))

create_report(df)
```

And I am making a report through DataExport, but it generates a bar plot in this way: [image]

But my desired plot is:

[image: Desired plot]

How could I customize this plot?

Comment: there  is a `config` option

Comment: It doesn't look like the function `plot_bar()` that makes the plot accepts arguments to add labels.

Comment: @adircinho: you can modify the function and overwrite the original one https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer/blob/master/R/plot_bar.r